How do I set a frame border color to change with the app theme?
I had no issues creating a frame in C# markup and it's been displaying just fine before now.
I tried to set the BorderColor property to dynamically change with the app theme using frame.SetAppThemeColor(Frame.BorderColor, Colors.White, Colors.Black).
    public class ExampleFrame : ContentView
    {
        public ExampleFrame()
        {

            Frame frame = new Frame
            {
                BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent,
                CornerRadius = 0,
                Margin = 0
            };

            frame.SetAppThemeColor(Frame.BorderColor, Colors.LightGray, Colors.White);

            Content = frame;
        }
    }

This gives me the following error under Frame.BorderColor:

'Rect' does not contain a definition for 'BorderColor' and no accessible extension method 'BorderColor' accepting a first argument of type 'Rect' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I assume I have the wrong property but I'm not sure what the right one would be since BorderBrush also produces the same error.

Frame.BorderColorProperty not Frame.BorderColor.

Do not use frame.

@H.A.H. is right. Frame docs says: The Frame control is marked as obsolete in .NET MAUI 9, and will be completely removed in a future release. The Border control should be used in its place. For more information see Border.

Please change the following code:
frame.SetAppThemeColor(Frame.BorderColor, Colors.LightGray, Colors.White);

to
frame.SetAppThemeColor(Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Frame.BorderColorProperty, Colors.LightGray, Colors.White);

In addition, the official document about the Frame in the .net maui 8.0 said:

The Frame class existed in Xamarin.Forms and is present in .NET MAUI for users who are migrating their apps from Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI. If you're building a new .NET MAUI app it's recommended to use Border instead, and to set shadows using the Shadow bindable property on VisualElement.

